# OAuth2 - Request Access Token - cURL

Tags: curl

After few hours of trying, I can't get it to work. I already tried other methods but they didn't seem to work either. I changed to cURL in the end because they want an URL-encoded body. Didn't work either as expected.

What I've to do is to make a request to obtain an access token.

```
POST https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token
```

Post Body (URL-encoded):

```
client_id=[your client ID]
&client_secret=[your client secret]
&grant_type=authorization_code
&redirect_uri=[your registered redirect URI]
&code=[code received from redirect URI]
```

My code so far:

```
<?php

// cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// call code
$usercode = $_GET['code'];

// Set some options - passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/oauth2/token',
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        usercode => $usercode,
        body => 'client_id=91th8b4i2ouxdfn660xojhu1eqfaonu&client_secret=dqhzi4h2k2rnb67bzbno9kva43uwmf9&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://decimo.net/token.php&code=', $usercode
    )
));
// Send request and save response to $response
$response = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

Hope that you can explain what I did wrong, in order to learn.
Thanks in advance for helping me.

Comment: What response are you getting? Also, you might want to blank out `client_id` and `client_secret`.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/RESTful-Integration-Guide.md,

"We do not offer password grants for the vast majority of cases. You need to explicitly get permission from twitch to use the password credential flow. It will fail with errors without our explicit permission."

You'll have to use the JavaScript API instead of the RESTful API.